# r to split column based on alpha numeric char

Tags: r

I have a column in data frame which combination of state code e.g TX and some id.

```
GaID
TX1
TX2
NJ2
```

What i wanted to do:

```
State, GaID
TX,TX1
TX,TX2
NJ,NJ2
```

I looked for split function but can not figure out how to split alphanumeric string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the condition to be two characters at the start of the string, the following are likely to be faster (only noticeable if you have a large dataset, though):

#### `substr`

```
substr(dat$GaID, 1, 2)
```

#### `sub`

```
sub("(^[A-Z]{2}).*", "\\1", dat$GaID)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is:

```
dat <- data.frame(GaID = c('TX1', 'TX2', 'NJ2'))

dat[, "State"] <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(dat$GaID), "\\d"))
dat[, 2:1]

##   State GaID
## 1    TX  TX1
## 2    TX  TX2
## 3    NJ  NJ2
```